# how to declare this type of states in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have angular code that looks like this

```
data={}
data['email']=$scope.emailid

and it was used inside an api call

$scope.checkifexisting=function(){
        data={}
        data['email']=$scope.emailid
        $http.post('/api/emailcheck',data).then(function(response,status){
```

I need to use translate it to reactjs.
so far i have tried it like this, but I'm getting an error

```
 this.state = {
      data: {
        email: ""        
      },
    };
```

the error that i'm getting is

```
var body = { > 18 | data['email']=this.state.email | ^ 19 | }; 20 | const options = { 21 | method: "POST", (null)
```

it will be used inside an api call

```
var body = {
data['email']=this.state.email
    };
```

This is for additional reference to see where email is used elsewhere in the file

```
<input
          type="text"
          name="email"
          placeholder="emailid"
          onChange={this.onchange}
        />

        onchange(e) {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
```

Comment: try this `var body = {
data['email']=this.state.data.email
    };` instead

Comment: @AtinSingh what about declaring it in this.state in the constructor block at the beginning. how do I declare it there?

Comment: I would say don't keep a nested state. That is don't keep `this.state = {
      data: {
        email: ""        
      },
    };` keep email and other stuff directly and not inside another object. Because in your onChange you are setting state something like this `this.setState({ email: e.target.value})` which is accessible this.state.email and is undefined at the start because in your state it is in `this.state.data.email`.